# C function that executes some code when the function that called it exits

Tags: c, pointers, logging, gcc, callback

I want a function which achieves something like the behavior shown in the pseudo C code listed.
I figure that this might be possible via the use of function pointers?

If this pattern I've dreamed up is terrible/impossible to implement, I'm more than happy to
accept alternatives as an answer if it achieves the same kind of functionality.

```
void log_func(const char* name, /*other args*/) {
  printf("called function: %s\n", name);
  if (/*calling function exited*/)
    printf("exited function: %s\n", name);
}

void example_func() {
  log_func(__func__); // __func__ macro is expanded to be function name as a c-string
  printf("This function does nothing\n");
}
```

output:

```
called function: example_func
This function does nothing
exited function: example_func
```

Comment: You'd probably have to monitor the stack some how.

Comment: nothing like this possible in C

Comment: The only way I can see is to instrumentalise the end of the calling function. Would that be an option?

Comment: IMO, the best bet is probably `log_func_call(__func__)` and `log_func_exit(__func__)` functions called either side the actual function call.  Or a wrapper technique as shown in [stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216776/stark)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73405950/15168).

Comment: I'm not sure i guess what do you want to achieve but maybe gcc instrumentation functions can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this works for functions returning void.  Would have to be more clever for arbitrary returns.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define WRAPPER
#ifdef WRAPPER
#define LOG_FUNC(fname, ...) \
    do { \
    printf("called function: %s\n", #fname); \
    fname(__VA_ARGS__); \
    printf("exited function: %s\n", #fname); \
    } while(0)
#else
#define LOG_FUNC(fname, ...) \
    fname(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
     
void phello(int n, char *s) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}

int main()
{  
    LOG_FUNC(phello, 3, "Hello, World!");
}
```

Output

```
called function: phello
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
exited function: phello
```